# Manhwa about a villain who prevents his aunt from getting killed by his uncle and is trying to kill his friend, the hero

Tags: story-identification, manga

It was about this guy who was the villain. In the first chapter, he prevents his aunt from getting killed by his uncle and is trying to kill his friend who is the hero. The hero is super powerful and is basically impossible to kill, and the villain mainly has the butterfly for his logo. I think at one point in one of the first chapters, he writes a bunch of equations on the window of his classroom and this crazy homeless-looking scientist sees them and gets super excited.

It was on Manganato and I just randomly dropped it. I believe it was Korean, but I read the version translated to English.

Comment: You said the hero was "super powerful and is basically impossible to kill." Did he have actual superhuman/supernatural powers? If so, what were they?

Comment: yes he did, and i believe he essentially went into an unconscious state where he was super powerful. another thing is that his dad is really rich and strict and is somewhat abusive/ neglectful

Comment: What colour was the main character's hair and was his hair long or short?

Comment: I believe it was believe it was black and somewhat long

Answer (score 3):

Likely you are talking about [Villain Initialization](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/q79voy3/villain-initialization).

The plot match with first few chapter of manhua. MC reincarnate and save his aunt by killing his uncle. He want to kill his nemesis (the hero and his best friend). Hero power always evolve when he is in great danger (that how early chapter interpret it). World nature is like cyberpunk world (high tech + Supernatural power)

I believe the butterfly for his hero costume is in cover  since that one is in few last chapter when he had a change of mind. Story is completed.